# Why does the developer console give different results for the same data input?

Tags: javascript, console

Why does the developer console give different results for the same data input?
Below is the code I checked in Chrome developer console.I am baffled how different outputs are delivered.

```
    // First time
    var a = [1, 2, 3];
    var b = [1, 2, 3];
    var c = "1,2,3";

    a == c; // true
    b == c; // true
    a == b; // false

    //Second time
    console.log(a == c);
    console.log(b == c);
    console.log(a == b);

    a = [1, 2, 3];
    b = [a, 2, 3];
    c = "1, 2, 3";
    console.log(a == c);  //false
    console.log(b == c);  //false
    console.log(a == b); //false
```

Comment: The 1st element in your `b` array is `a` array. Is that intentional?

Comment: They're not the same? In the second one you have `b = [a, 2, 3]`

Answer (score 0):

```
b = [1, 2, 3]; // first
b = [a, 2, 3]; // second
```

the first elements of the arrays are different

ps avoid '==' and use '===' in production.

Answer (score 0):

All the values of your second execution are false because none of the values are equal.

var c = "1,2,3" is not the same as c = "1, 2, 3" because of the spaces in the second string.

var b = [1, 2, 3] is not same as b = [a, 2, 3] because of the different first element in the second array.

Try the below code

```
// First time
var a = [1, 2, 3];
var b = [1, 2, 3];
var c = "1,2,3";

a == c;
b == c;
a == b;

//Second time
console.log(a == c);
console.log(b == c);
console.log(a == b);

a = [1, 2, 3];
b = [1, 2, 3];
c = "1,2,3";
console.log(a == c);
console.log(b == c);
console.log(a == b);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
// First time
var a = [1, 2, 3];
var b = [1, 2, 3];
var c = "1,2,3";

a == c; // true
b == c; // true
a == b; // false

//Second time
console.log(a == c);
console.log(b == c);
console.log(a == b);

a = [1, 2, 3];
b = [a, 2, 3];
c = "1, 2, 3";
console.log(a == c);  //false
console.log(b == c);  //false
console.log(a == b); //false
```

The second set looks like this:

```
a = [1, 2, 3];
b = [[1,2,3],2,3]; -> Jagged Array;
c = "1,2,3"
```